# Deserializing JSON response into specific class objects

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization

I am trying to serialize a JSON result from an API. The result has the following structure:

```
{
 "Version" : "123",
 "Message" : "some string",
 "Status" : 200,
 "Result" : { 
       "Events" :  [ {"Subprop1" : "some_value"}, {"Subprop2" : "some_value"} ],
       "Merch" :   [ {"Subprop2" : "some_value"}, {"Subprop2" : "some_value"} ],
       "Tickets" : [ {"Subprop3" : "some_value"}, {"Subprop2" : "some_value"} ],
       "Seasons" : [ {"Subprop4" : "some_value"}, {"Subprop2" : "some_value"} ] 
 }
}
```

My question is: how do I deserialize this properly into objects of the classes I made ? I've made classes for each of Result's proprieties (i.e. Event, Merch etc)

My code so far:

```
dynamic resultJSON = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response.Content);
dynamic data = resultJSON.Result;
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray events = resultJSON.Result.Events;
```

`resultJSON` contains everything in an object. How do I deserialize this in their own classes? And avoid JArray

Update here is my `Event` class

```
    public class Event
    {
      public int OrderId { get; set; }
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Name{ get; set; }
      public string Type { get; set; }
    
}

public class ListEvents
{
    public List<Event> Events { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried making a Class to represent your data structure, rather than dynamic?

Comment: Yes, but for Events/Merch etc. Should I do it for the whole response ?

Comment: You can make `Result` a dictionary. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net

Comment: I am getting "'Cannot implicitly convert type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,object>''" when trying `Dictionary<string, dynamic> data = resultJSON.Result;`

Comment: Can you post your classes? Also, stop using `dynamic`.

Comment: Ive added the `Event` class to the OP.

Comment: Are the properties on `Events`, `Merch` etc completely dynamic or are they a fixed structure? Because `subProp1` and the like doesnt look _at all_ like the class you've included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define Json as Classes:

```
public class Response
{
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public Result Result { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public Event[] Events { get; set; }
    public Merch[] Merch { get; set; }
    public Ticket[] Tickets { get; set; }
    public Season[] Seasons { get; set; }
}

public class Event
{
    public string Subprop1 { get; set; }
    public string Subprop2 { get; set; }
}

public class Merch
{
    public string Subprop2 { get; set; }
}

public class Ticket
{
    public string Subprop3 { get; set; }
    public string Subprop2 { get; set; }
}

public class Season
{
    public string Subprop4 { get; set; }
    public string Subprop2 { get; set; }
}
```

If your using Visual Studio you can copy the json and use `Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON as Classes`

Then deserialize :

```
var response = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Response>(jsonString);
```

Comment: this worked! Ive spent some time to make sure all properties are mapped correctly and now the deserialization works as it should , thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the values in the items in the `Events` array in the JSON actually match the fields in the `Event` class you've shown (rather than the dummy data in your example), then you can use `JArray`'s `ToObject` method to convert the JArray into a list of events.

This avoids having to generate C# classes to represent other parts of the data which you aren't really interested in:

```
    dynamic resultJSON = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
    ListEvents list = new ListEvents();
    list.Events = ((JArray)resultJSON.Result.Events).ToObject<List<Event>>();
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nr5ME3